# datatype of the answer given while using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

Could anyone tell me what would be the data type of the answer given, while using itertools.combination(iterable, r)??

```
from itertools import combinations
def rSubset(arr, r):
 
    return list(combinations(arr, r))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    r = 2
    print (rSubset(arr, r))
```

Comment: Read the docs: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). "The module functions all construct and return iterators".

Comment: You will find the *type()* built-in very useful

Comment: thank you!  I will check the link Mattis sir. I Tried what you said OLvin, it returns list :)

Comment: @gajhanaselvi only because you made it a list. See my Answer for clarification

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT! @OlvinRoght , so I removed the list in line 3, then I tried, IT SAYS <class 'itertools.combinations'>,thanks, could you explain me what this datatype mean?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itertools.combinations returns a reference to an itertools.combinations class which is iterable. To clarify this using your data:

```
from itertools import combinations

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for comb in combinations(arr, 2):
  print(comb)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```